# TWTSideMenuViewController open to right not left

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am going to user TWTSideMenuViewController in my app, but my app is going to have a right menu not a left one. So, i want to know how to edit TWTSideMenuViewController https://github.com/twotoasters/TWTSideMenuViewController  to open to right not to left.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No problem! Modify the `closeTransformForMenuView` and `openTransformForMenuView` methods as follows:

```
- (CGAffineTransform)closeTransformForMenuView
{
    CGFloat transformSize = 1.0f / self.zoomScale;
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformScale(self.menuViewController.view.transform, transformSize, transformSize);
    return CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform,
                                      -(-(CGRectGetMidX(self.view.bounds)) - self.edgeOffset.horizontal),
                                      -self.edgeOffset.vertical);
}

- (CGAffineTransform)openTransformForView:(UIView *)view
{
    CGFloat transformSize = self.zoomScale;
    CGAffineTransform newTransform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(view.transform, -(CGRectGetMidX(view.bounds) + self.edgeOffset.horizontal), self.edgeOffset.vertical);
    return CGAffineTransformScale(newTransform, transformSize, transformSize);
}
```